# How to go back in PyCharm while browsing code like we have a back button in eclipse?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, intellij-plugin

While browsing the code in PyCharm(community edition) how to go back to the previously browsed section? I am looking for eclipse back button type functionality with Pycharm.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

in pycharm you have `view` in view please make sure that `toolbar` is checked
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I can see the toolbar now. I tried to search about back button and never knew it could be in toolbar.
Thanks.

Comment: In latest pycharm ..the you need to click View -> Apearance -> Toolbar

Answer (score 34):

You could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> (which is more convenient from my point of view) or clicking arrows as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24548487/3240679).

Comment: Yup. And `Cmd + Alt + Left Arrow` on OS X.

Answer (score 7):

You can also go to Navigate->Back

[image: navigate back in PyCharm]

Answer (score 7):

**Ubuntu 16.04 defines `Ctrl + Alt + Left` as a workspace switch shortcut**

Then it does nothing on Pycharm.

So you have to either disable the Ubuntu shortcut with:

- dash
- keyboard
- shortcuts
- navigation

or redefine the PyCharm shortcuts to something else.

Linux distro desktop devs: please make all desktop system wide shortcuts contain the Super key.

Comment: Using ubuntu16.04 + PyCharm 2017.2.3 `Alt + Left` works by default

Comment: @eplaut hmmm, to me it seems to just go to the tab at the left, not to the previous code location (specially different since Ctrl + click to jump to definition reuses existing tabs).

Comment: Can you explain how to disable it on ubuntu?

Comment: I simply change PyCharm keyboard shortcuts for `Back` and `Forward` to `Alt+<-` & `Alt+->` iso of changing Ubuntu wokspace switcher shortcuts. Need to restart PyCharm after assigning new shortcuts.

Comment: @sagarr yes, this is also a valid solution, added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**In Ubuntu:**

Navigate back

```
Shift + Alt + Left Arrow
```

Navigate forward

```
Shift + Alt + Right Arrow
```

[image]

## **In Windows:**

Navigate back / forward

```
Ctrl + Alt + Left / Right Arrow
```

## **In MAC:**

Navigate back / forward

```
Cmd + Alt + Left Arrow
```

Answer (score 0):

Able to enable Forward/Back button on latest pycharm.

Right-click the toolbar and select Add to Main Toolbar and select Back/Forward

[image]

Reference is from : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/13224717402002-Where-did-the-forward-and-back-buttons-go-in-the-new-PyCharm-layout-