# PyCharm: how to go back after navigating to some other part of the file?

Tags: pycharm

How do I go back after navigating to some other part of the py file? For example, I use F12 to go to function definition, but I don't see a way to go back? I am using `Alt + <` and `Alt + >` in Eclipse and Visual Studio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to go back in PyCharm while browsing code like we have a back button in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548398/how-to-go-back-in-pycharm-while-browsing-code-like-we-have-a-back-button-in-ecli)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ctrl + Alt + left should do the job. 
Ctrl + Alt + right will navigate forward

Answer (score 0):

Use Alt+Up/Alt+Down keyboard shortcuts. More info here: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/navigating-between-methods-and-tags.html

Comment: This navigates between methods, not my previous positions.

Comment: I am sorry. I mis-understood the question.