# Pycharm go back after ctrl+click

Tags: navigation, keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm and quite use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click to look up a declaration of a function. After that I want to return to my code and I have to scroll down (often a lot). Is there a useful shortcut to go back to the function usage after you looked up its declaration?

The closest I found was <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> to go last edit location. However, often the function I'm checking is not last edited snippet of code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to go back in PyCharm while browsing code like we have a back button in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548398/how-to-go-back-in-pycharm-while-browsing-code-like-we-have-a-back-button-in-ecli)

Answer (score 6):

Navigate | Back (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> in the default keymap)

Answer (score 2):

In Pycharm community 2018.1 in Windows this is alt+left to jump back, alt+right to jump forward again.